# Get invalid projection matrix and hidden custom THREE.js objects with Forge Viewer 6.5.2

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Having upgraded from Forge Viewer 6.4.1 to 6.5.2 I'm getting a couple of problems:

The `projectionMatrix` from `viewer.navigation.getCamera()` has Infinity elements, e.g. :

```
0: 1.491671085357666
1: 0
2: 0
3: 0
4: 0
5: 1.7320507764816284
6: 0
7: 0
8: 0
9: 0
10: -Infinity
11: -1
12: 0
13: 0
14: -Infinity
15: 0
```

Also, I'm displaying some custom THREE.js pointclouds, which gets hidden for certain camera viewpoints. This only happens if I haven't loaded any proper SVF models with Forge.

Note that I'm loading an SVF model of "invisible triangles" to initialize the forge viewer, in order to be able to view the custom pointclouds without any proper SVFs loaded. The triangles should then span the entire scene. This used to work with 6.4.1.

Any idea on how to make this work for version 6.5.2?

**Edit**
Here's some of the camera parameters when getting Infinity values in the projection matrix:

```
camera: {
    ...
    far: 0.07279428289764538,
    near: 0.07279428289764538,
    matrix: Z.Matrix4
        elements: Float32Array(16)
        0: 0.7071067690849304 1: -0.7071067690849304 2: 1.2355465983659997 e-8 3: 0 4: 0.09901473671197891 5: 0.0990147516131401 6: 0.9901475310325623 7: 0 8: -0.7001400589942932 9: -0.7001400589942932 10: 0.1400279998779297 11: 0 12: 335.91473388671875 13: 307.50555419921875 14: 103.9164047241211 15: 1
     projectionMatrix: Z.Matrix4
       elements: Float32Array(16)
       0: 1.491671085357666 1: 0 2: 0 3: 0  4: 0 5: 1.7320507764816284 6: 0 7: 0 8: 0 9: 0 10: -Infinity 11: -1 12: 0 13: 0 14: -Infinity 15: 0 
     fov: 60, 
     position: Z.Vector3
       x: 338.37971488661725
       y: 309.97052196410925
       z: 103.42340670070932

    quaternion: Z.Quaternion
       w: 0.6975223178288207
       x: 0.6058184615827841
       y: -0.250938228461858
       z: -0.288923200051608

    scale: Z.Vector3
       x: 1
       y: 1
       z: 1
}
```

The viewer is loaded in the following manner:

```
Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(urn_base_64, (doc) => {
     const viewables = Autodesk.Viewing.Document
                    .getSubItemsWithProperties(doc.getRootItem(), {'type': 'geometry'}, true);

    const initialViewable = viewables[0];
    const svfUrl = doc.getViewablePath(initialViewable);
    let mat = new THREE.Matrix4();
    mat.compose(globalOffset, new THREE.Quaternion(), scale);

    const modelOptions = {
        applyScaling: {to: 'm'},
        placementTransform: mat,
        worldUpVector: new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1),
        sharedPropertyDbPath: doc.getPropertyDbPath(),
    };

    viewer.start(svfUrl, modelOptions,
         (model) => {
         ... 
    })
```

The svf here represents an .obj model consisting of 2 triangles at `(-1 -1 -1)` and `(1, 1, 1)`. 
`scale` is `Vector3 {x: 132, y: 240, z: 59}` and `globalOffset` is `Vector3 {x: 403, y: 330, z: 103.5}`.
The intention is to offset and scale the 2 triangles to span the scene, centered at `globalOffset` with width, depth and height equal to `scale`.

Comment: is the `-Infinity` causing problem or do you need a way to make it work now? I'll check more on the infinity.

Comment: The -Infinity in the matrix usually means that the near and far distances are equal. Can you share more info on the camera values, near, far, fov, aspect, position, quaternion, scale, target and bounding box of the scene?

Comment: The infinity is causing the problem. For now, I just reverted to the previous version. As you can see, the near and far distances are equal. Any idea why? I did not make any other changes then updating forge, so it looks like there's some internal Forge stuff that is causing it.

Comment: I am not sure why the near and far distances are equal. Normally they are set when the renderer runs, so maybe you are using the camera before the first render? If the scene has any depth, then the near and far distances should not be equal. Could you try setting the planes and see what happens. maybe near: 0.1 and far: 1000?